# Link two controllers get() cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to join two controllers.
I have a controller Articles with a view function :

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
       $article = $this->Articles->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        $this->set('article', $article);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['article']);
    }
```

Each article has an associated user. So I have a controller Users.
Now I can have the user_id for the article (in database). 
Is it possible to access the username in the User table with the user_id in the Articles table? With a get() function.

For example I know how to do it with find() :

```
$this->set('articles', $this->Articles->find('all')->contain(['Users']));
```

But is it possible with get()? For a particular article.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to get some articles by user id?

Comment: For an article, I want to write the username of the author and not only the id. The user_id is in the Article table. And the username in the User Table.

Comment: So, you want to search an article by the user name?

Comment: I just want to see the username in the view function. Now in an article,  I can have : "Article written by 1" and I want "Article written by Admin" . Where Admin is user_id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have username field in users table:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->displayField('username');

    }
}
```

Articles table

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your Articles controller:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
   $article = $this->Articles->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);
    $this->set('article', $article);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['article']);
}
```

in your articles view

```
<?= $article->has('user') ? $this->Html->link($article->user->username, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $article->user->id]) : '' ?>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I learnt a great thing thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

In the get() function, just add Users to the contain array:

```
'contain' => ['Users']
```

Comment: That's what I tried. And I have this error : "Articles is not associated with Users"

Comment: Then you need to associate the tables :)

Comment: Yes, with foreign key

Comment: I have a foreign key in cascade between user_id in Articles and id in User. But I have the same error. Should I update something with cakephp?